# Deploying Angular 5 application to own infrastructure with GitLab CI/CD

Tags: deployment, angular5, gitlab-ci

I´m trying to deploy an Angular 5 application (created with Angular CLI) with GitLab CI/CD. The runner is already registered for the project (installed on a VM with Ubuntu). Now I wonder how I can deploy my application to a server, which is reachable from another machine.

TL;DR

- How can I deploy an Angular 5 application to my own server?
- How should a gitlab-ci.yaml file look like in this case?
- Are there best practices for using GitLab CI in this case?

Thanks for the answers in advance, I simply can not figure it out from the documentation.